# Python/Selenium Displaying Instance of Browser to User

Tags: python, selenium

Is it possible to show a user (via some ui/window) the instance of the browser so that the program will wait and the user can actually interact with the webpage, browse as usual, and then at some point allow the program to continue running.

Comment: use browser.wait()

Comment: But how do you run headless, wait, emulate the process of browsing via normal broswer so that user can browse, then resume program via headless mode?

Comment: You can put an `input()` call wherever you want the browser to "wait" for the user to interact with the session and after the user presses enter in the stdin window, the program will continue with the rest of its code. Selenium has no way to recognise on its own when a user is done browsing.

Comment: You can't have headless go non-headless suddenly in between, if that is what you are looking for